# Force refresh LWC component to get latest changes from Server

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a Quick Action, which invokes lwc, which is used to update a record.
This component contains a custom multiselect lookup, which get populated with default value based on click of Quick action.

Once I update the lookup value, the correct value are getting saved in the record, but if I click again on the Quick action it is still showing the old selected value instead of latest one.
if I refresh the tab, then I'm seeing correct value.

js:

```
@wire(selectedContact, {selectedRecord:'$recordId'})
    contactSelected({error, data}) {
        if(error){
            this.error = error;
            console.log('>>> errrosss.....  '+this.error);
        }else if(data){
            this.initialSelection = data;
            console.log('>>> selected Contactss.....  '+JSON.stringify(this.initialSelection));
        }
    }
```

Aura Component:

```
<aura:component>
<c:lwcComponent recordId="{!v.recordId}" onclose="{!c.close}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Aura Controller:

```
({
    close  : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: are you using an aura component as a wrapper for this Lwc?

Comment: Yes, I’m using aura

Comment: Fire the refreshview event from the aura component when you save the record.

Comment: That I’m already doing

Comment: can you add the code where you are calling that?

Comment: I have modified the Question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104048/discussion-between-rahul-gawale-and-salesforce-developer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and the solution was to put `refreshApex`inside .then() method after successfully calling the server.

Here is the working example i used

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import findSomething from '@salesforce/apex/ApexController.findMethod';
import changeSomething from '@salesforce/apex/ApexController.changeMethod';
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';

findSomething
changeSomething
@track paramForChangeOne
@track paramForChangeTwo

@wire(findSomething, { paramOne: '$paramOne', paramTwo: '$paramTwo' }) findSomething;

callFromHtml(){
        changeSomething({paramForChangeOne: this.paramForChangeOne, paramForChangeTwo: this.paramForChangeTwo})
        .then(result => {
            if(result){
                this.showNotification('success', 'Success Message', '');
            }
            // refreshing table data using refresh apex(HERE NEEDS TO BE SET)
            refreshApex(this.findSomething);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Here is the documentation link for your reference

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex

Comment: It’s still not working

Comment: Show me the code and read documentation too